# Как проверить переменную на существование самой себя при объявлении

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Заранее извиняюсь за то что вопрос может показаться достаточно странным)

Есть результат фильтрации массива:

```
const smallArr = arr.filter((i) => условие);
```

Сложностью является то, что он объявляется внутри render() и фильтрация повторяется при каждой перерисовке. Повторения фильтрации хотелось бы избежать.

Мне нравится простота этого решения, но оно конечно невозможно:

```
const smallArr = smallArr ? smallArr : arr.filter((i) => условие);
```

Если не выносить объявление переменной и фильтрацию за `render()`, то есть ли еще варианты решения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если массив `arr` один и тот же для разных вызовов функции:

```
if (!arr.smallFiltered)
  arr.smallFiltered = arr.filter((i) => условие);
const smallArr = arr.smallFiltered;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Gasu Пожалуйста. Успехов!